# AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 500', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE'

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am learning React and Redux and came up with this error.  I am not sure what is driving this error.  I do know it is in CartActions.js and pretty sure it has to do with my local storage but not sure.  Can someone please steer me in the right direction?  Maybe explain this error and how to fix it?

cartActions.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {
    CART_ADD_ITEM,
    CART_REMOVE_ITEM,
    CART_SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS,

    CART_SAVE_PAYMENT_METHOD,
} from '../constants/cartConstants'


export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}/`)
    dispatch({
        type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
        payload: {
            product: data._id,
            name: data.name,
            image: data.image,
            price: data.price,
            countInStock: data.countInStock,
            qty
        }
    })
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
}



// export const removeFromCart = (id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
//     dispatch({
//         type: CART_REMOVE_ITEM,
//         payload: id,
//     })

//     localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
// }


// export const saveShippingAddress = (data) => (dispatch) => {
//     dispatch({
//         type: CART_SAVE_SHIPPING_ADDRESS,
//         payload: data,
//     })

//     localStorage.setItem('shippingAddress', JSON.stringify(data))
// }

// export const savePaymentMethod = (data) => (dispatch) => {
//     dispatch({
//         type: CART_SAVE_PAYMENT_METHOD,
//         payload: data,
//     })

//     localStorage.setItem('paymentMethod', JSON.stringify(data))
// }
```

Comment: An HTTP 500 response means that an error occurred *on the server*.  Check your browser's debugging tools to see if there's any more information about the error in the server's network response.  But aside from that, your debugging needs to include the server-side functionality.

Comment: is there more to the url you're fetching from with the axios.get request?

Comment: If I change     const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}/`)
to     const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/products/${1}/`) I don't get the errors but don't return the product either.